# Had two versions of Ruby installed. Removed the older one and somehow got stuck

Tags: ruby, command-line, rvm

I'm just getting started with the command line, so this might be very basic.

I installed Sass and when I typed `sass -v` it told me I was running a deprecated version of Ruby. When I ran `ruby -v` it said I was on `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin-11.4.0]`

I used Homebrew to install the current version and it worked, but running `ruby -v`and `sass -v`yielded the same results as above. I ran `brew doctor`a few times and fixed everything it came up with, but the problem seemed to be that I had the new version in `usr/local` and the old version in `.rvm/bin` at the same time.

I ran `rvm uninstall 1.9.3`, but the files are still there.

Now when I run `ruby -v`it takes a minute or two and then says

`/Users/username/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/danielpternes/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/username/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/danielpternes/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0`

`sass -v`takes just as long and shows me the same message.

Any advice on what exactly is wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have 1.9.3 installed via rvm, I'd suggest the following:

1) Blow away your rvm installation entirely.  You can do this with `rvm implode`.

2) `brew uninstall ruby`

3) Reinstall rvm (instructions at at https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

This will eliminate the conflict, give you a current version of ruby, and enable you to enjoy the goodness of rvm that you probably envisioned when you first installed it, such as trivially simple installation and management of multiple Rubies (including jruby), deletion of older versions of Ruby, and management of gem directories for each Ruby installation.

Answer (score 0):

`rvm remove` is the preferred way of removing rubies from rvm. It remove the ruby and it's source files, it will also get rid of aliases, wrappers, environments and any associated binaries - in other words, it cleans up most of the install.

Try using `rvm remove 1.9.3`
[Reference link rvm remove / rvm uninstall](https://rvm.io/rubies/removing)